# How do I extract this json Array inside of an Array with Volley?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

[json Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu59X.png)I'm trying to extract a list (Array) of data out of a Json Object but i don't I don't know to. it's the value of "ingredients" i'm trying to extract. I have trying to extract it as a string but it comes out un-formatted. I have also provide a image of the raw json`enter code here`. if I try to extract it as 'cake.optJSONArray' I get a java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.util.List
I have added more code to help the question make sense (fingers crossed I didn't make it more confusing).

```
   try {

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject cake = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String cakeId = cake.optString("id");
                    String cakeName = cake.optString("name");


                    List<Ingredients> ingredients = (List<Ingredients>) cake.optJSONArray("ingredients");

                    mCakeList.add(new CakesItem(cakeId,ingredients, cakeName));
                }
```

public class CakesItem {

```
private String mId;
private List<Ingredients> mIngredients;
private String mName;

public CakesItem(String cakeId, Lists <Ingrediets> ingredients String cakeName) {
    mId = cakeId;
    mIngredients = ingredients;
    mName = cakeName;

}
```

public class Ingredients implements Parcelable {

```
private double quantity;
private String measure, ingredient;


public Ingredients() {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what JSON library you are using, but if you import org.json.JSONArray, then if your cake is a org.json.JSONObject that you got out of the JSONObject response returned from Volley, you would use this syntax:

```
JSONObject cake = response.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray ingredients = cake.getJSONArray("ingredients");
```

Then, it is up to you to get the values out of the JSONArray ingredients into your List. It would look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject cake = response.getJSONObject(i);

    String cakeId = cake.optString("id");
    String cakeName = cake.optString("name");

    JSONArray JSONingredients = cake.optJSONArray("ingredients");

    List<Ingredients> ingredients = new List<Ingredients>();

    for (int j = 0; j < JSONingredients.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject item = JSONingredients.getObject(j);

        String measure = item.getString(“measure”);
        String ingredient = item.getString(“ingredient”);
        Double quantity = item.getDouble(“quantity”);

        Ingredients item2 = new Ingredients(measure, ingredient, quantity);
        ingredients.add(item2);
      } 


      mCakeList.add(new CakesItem(cakeId,ingredients, cakeName));
    }
```

Comment: Oh yes, that's works but it still producing un-formatted text because inside the JSONArray ("ingredients") is a whole Array of objects which are Quantity, Measure and Ingredients and I want those values formatted thus I had initially created 2 objects  (CakeItem and Ingredients)

Comment: Thank you that worked i only had to turn the List into An ArrayList.